# How to create custom Controller's action in Express.JS

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, express

I'm starting with Node.JS and Express.JS, I would like to follow MVC pattern. I found **Express-Resource** (https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource) It seems good but it does not solve me problem 100% because as you can see it follow REST scheme and ALL the POST requests are sent to **create** method, it is a problem for me, I try to explain it with an example:

I have a control panel where I can, show, edit, create, delete a customer.

when I finish to edit the costumer I send the details with a POST request, if I use that module(express-resource) "create" method will be called automatically, but it is pointless to me, I would like to call actions depending of the URLs, so:

`/users/create:` I call it when i need to create a user account. It should accepts GET and POST

**GET:** to see the form that allow me to create the user

**POST:** to send the informations when I finish

So I always would like a path like:

```
/PATH/:action/:params (like: /users/edit/1)
```

But I would like to avoid calling **create** method, when I do not create anything.

Comment: It seems to me that express-resource is modeled after the REST pattern, and you want something else, similar to RPC. In that case, express-resource is probably not the right module for you. Why not build in on top of Express, and set up your routing to your liking?

Comment: @LinusGThiel yes I need to develop it myself, because it is not good for my purpose

Answer (score 1):

Why not using bare bone express?

```
app.get("/users/:userid/create", function (req, res, next) {
    // serve the form
});

app.post("/users/:userid/create", function (req, res, next) {
    // save in the database
});
```

Comment: @JanJomgboom becaue if i have many pages i need to have many many routes like those

Comment: What about
app.get("/:entity/:id/create", function( ... ) {  ... } )
?